# Macbook M2Pro - Error running '__rvm_make -j12'

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, rosetta

Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /Users/scari/.rvm/log/1706650388_ruby-2.7.3/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

When trying to install ruby-2.7.3 on a MacBook m2 pro - Ventura 13.0

Running under rosetta 2

make.log

```
 return rb_funcall(ePsychSyntaxError, rb_intern("new"), 6,
ossl.c:311:14: warning: 'ERR_get_error_line_data' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        while ((e = ERR_get_error_line_data(&file, &line, &data, &flags))) {
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1/include/openssl/err.h:424:1: note: 'ERR_get_error_line_data' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    rb_funcall(p->value, rb_intern("compile_error"), 1, str);
    rb_funcall(p->value, rb_intern("compile_error"), 1, str);
    rb_funcall(p->value, rb_intern("compile_error"), 1, str);
    rb_funcall(p->value, rb_intern("compile_error"), 1, str);
    if(!ENGINE_finish(e)) ossl_raise(eEngineError, NULL);
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RSA_SSLV23_PADDING'
115 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [ossl_pkey_rsa.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Comment: Seems like it might be an openssl issue. Maybe some of these suggestions can help: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5379, https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5128, https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5404#issuecomment-1806701326